# Oracle SQL query to list missing filenames from a sequence of filenames

Tags: oracle

Is there any way of listing the missing filenames from the following sequence of filenames using Oracle SQL?

The filenames are stored in table1. There are two types of filenames type1 and type2. The filenames are not necessarily stored in the correct sequence number order. For each filetype there should be ten files (sequence numbered 001-010).

The filenames are in the following format:

filetype.type1.seq.001.dat

filetype.type1.seq.004.dat

filetype.type2.seq.001.dat

filetype.type1.seq.006.dat

filetype.type2.seq.006.dat

filetype.type1.seq.007.dat

filetype.type1.seq.010.dat

filetype.type2.seq.004.dat

filetype.type1.seq.002.dat

filetype.type1.seq.003.dat

filetype.type2.seq.005.dat

filetype.type2.seq.008.dat

filetype.type2.seq.009.dat

filetype.type2.seq.010.dat

The missing files from this sequence would be:

filetype.type1.seq.005.dat, filetype.type1.seq.008.dat, filetype.type1.seq.009.dat
filetype.type2.seq.002.dat, filetype.type2.seq.003.dat, filetype.type2.seq.007.dat

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can generate the filenames at runtime, e.g.:

```
select 'filetype.type' || typeno || '.seq.' || to_char(seqno,'fm000') || '.dat'
       as filename
from (select rownum as typeno from dual connect by level <= 2)
    ,(select rownum as seqno from dual connect by level <= 10)
minus
select filename from table1;
```

Comment: Jeffrey - your answer works great thanks.   Now if the list of files was received daily and the sequence number always incremented, is there a way to list missing files each day?

Comment: To make things easier I would add a date value into the filename 'YYYYMMDD' so that you only have to test the last couple of days files and the SEQ number would max at '99999'  new file name format would look like 'filetype.type1.seq.00005.20120830.dat'   thanks again.

Comment: You would need to know ahead of time how many files are expected each day. Otherwise, you'd have to check every possible sequence value. The idea of adding a datestamp is a good one. Even better, have the date stored as another column in the table.

Answer (score 0):

```
select filename
from ref_table
MINUS
select distinct filename
from table1;
```

The ref_table would contain the list of all possible filenames.